# Mathematical induction by inequality

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove $n^3>2n-2$ for all $n∈N $

step 1: claim (1) is 1 > 0
LHS > RHS

step 2: assume claim (k) is true, that is
$k^3>2k-2$

Prove claim (k + 1)
$(k+1)^3>2(k+1)-2$

LHS = $(k+1)^3$
= $k^3+3k^2+3k+1$
$>(2k-2)+3k^2+3k+1$

Then I am struck, I am not sure how to get to $2(k+1)-2$

Comment: Unless you're required to use induction, this is quite straight forward.  $n \ge 2 \implies n^3> 2n > 2n-2$ .  We have $n=1$ to verify separately.

Comment: Yup, I need to use induction, but I do not understand why and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$3k^2+3k = 3k(k+1)\ge 6 >1.$$